# Responsive Image to align vertically centered in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got success in getting the img horizontal aligned using **.center-block** class but for `vertically center aligned` I am getting seemingly anomalous results. Can anyone please tell what's wrong with the code?

```
<style>
   .center-y{vertical-align:middle;}
</style>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ">
      <img class="animated center-block img-responsive center-y" src="website%20logo.png" alt="logo" onload="animate_in();" width="800" height="600"  id="img_logo" onclick="animate_out();" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amigoo/2mg1o2b1/1/)

### Update:

I figured out a way to do it using pure CSS i.e

```
<style>
  img{
     max-height: 90%;
     max-width: 90%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;               
     left: 0;
     right: 0;             
     margin: auto;                
     border: 2px solid rgb(44,44,44);                           
   }


</style>
  <img class="animated" src="website%20logo.png" alt="logo" onload="animate_in();" width="800" height="600" id="img_logo" onclick="animate_out();" />
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amigoo/48gmyofm/)

It works great but you see image is no more responsive? :) So how can I achieve the same thing with the incorporation of Bootstrap  class `img-responsive`?

Comment: Just a FYI, you're missing the dot on the `center-y` in your styles.

Comment: Vertical center doesn't work that way. There's many ways depending on the situation, here's some stuff to try: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/ http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/ http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it, I missed dot while posting on SO. It's alright in my code @Moogs

Comment: I think that `vertical-align` works only on `inline`, not `block` elements.

Comment: Well then `img` is an inline element, it should work on it :)

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq `img` is an inline element, but `.img-responsive` transform it to a `block`. You could try [flex](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/).

Comment: I know, and because of that `col-md-x` gets the height of the `img`, so you can't really vertical-align it. At least that's how I'm picturing the whole thing at the moment, can you give us jsfiddle?

And the comment above could also be what's wrong, I don't know what `img-responsive` class does.

Comment: @azeós I have tried by removing the classes which makes it Block level but no success. Thanks for telling about `flex` but I find there are so much dependencies for using it. Also, I am not sure if it remains mobile compatible after using `flex`.

Comment: @Davion I have put JSfiddle. I also have tried removing the div so that it don't get the height of div's classes but still same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out using JQuery, it's solution is simple using Jquery. Still wondering if there is css way to acheive it ;)

Here is the solution code:

```
 $( window ).on('load resize',function() {
                    window_size = $(window).height();
                    img_ht= $('#img_logo').height();

                    difference_ht=(window_size) - (img_ht);
                    console.log(difference_ht);
                    margin_ht=(difference_ht/2).toFixed();
                    margin_ht+="px";
                    $("#img_logo").css({"margin-top": margin_ht});
            });
```

and the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amigoo/2mg1o2b1/2/)